# IntelliJ How to remove missing package in class

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

How to remove missing packages in class

You can see on the picture that some packages are wrong, I juste need to automatically remove there whereas remove line by line, file by file

[image]

An idea ? Can't find shortcut or action in intellij menu

Comment: Please mark as answered if below answer helped

Answer (score 1):

If the imported classes are not used in the java file, you can use "Optimize Imports" (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>) to remove any unused imports.

This does not work if the imported classes are actually used, and for good reason.  Normally, when you have red lines under imports, it is because you have an unresolved dependency, and you should add the correct jar file, or you should remove the code that uses the unresolved library.

Another option is to activate *Optimize imports on the fly* in Settings -> Editor -> General -> Auto Import but this will also not fix or touch an invalid import statement.

Comment: thanks for the edit @meistermeier. I only recently noticed that SO uses markdown syntax. I know a little markdown, but it is not a syntax i'm fully familiar with.

Comment: It's not unuse import but missing import because I change packages in other projets. Juste want IntelliJ remove there missing package, then I can import good package with "Optimize imports on fly" or Ctrl + Alt + o

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of files with missing imports in them, you can fix them in just 2 steps doing the following:

1. In the **Project Tool Window** (to enter press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>) select the multiple files where you want to remove missed imports.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> to remove unused imports from your all selected files.

[image]

Read more about [Optimizing Imports](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/optimizing-imports.html) feature.

Answer (score -1):

Looks Till latest Intelliji Community version, There is no option for this.

If you are too curious to solve this through code, you may a write a simple code to locate if imported class exists are not using below

```
try {
    Class.forName("org.abc.Rocker");
    return true;
} catch(Exception e) {
    return false;
}
```

This snippet returns true if exists and not if not.

Like wise for star imports, use the below snippet.

```
Package pac = Package.getPackage("org.abc");

if(null != pac){
  pac.toString();
  return true;
}else{
  return false;
}
```

With a small util, you could solve the above scenario.